# Need help in php to parse key =>value in json when value again have nested key=>value?

Tags: php, json

I am new in php . I have json as below

```
{
    "ext": {
        "output": "vast"
    },
    "cur": ["USD"],
    "allimps": 0,
    "tmax": 350,
    "regs": {},
    "imp": [{
        "ext": {
            "viewabilitymeasurability": 2
        },
        "bidfloor": 0.02,
        "bidfloorcur": "USD",
        "id": "1",
        "video": {
            "boxingallowed": 1,
            "ext": {
                "skippability": 1,
                "incentivized": 2,
                "clickability": 1,
                "instream": 2
            },
            "sequence": 1,
            "protocol": 2,
            "linearity": 1,
            "maxduration": 30,
            "startdelay": 0,
            "playbackmethod": [2],
            "protocols": [2, 5],
            "minduration": 15,
            "mimes": ["video/mp4"]
        },
        "instl": 1
    }],
    "audienceSegment": 0,
    "site": {
        "ref": "http://imasdk.googleapis.com/js/core/bridge3.145.0_en.html",
        "domain": "imasdk.googleapis.com",
        "publisher": {
            "ext": {
                "direct": 2
            },
            "domain": "imasdk.googleapis.com",
            "id": "8678"
        },
        "id": "eba5e1348aaa8dbce4044cdb1e54141c"
    },
    "at": 2,
    "bcat": [],
    "id": "9892d4df-03da-4981-a4ca-7172fd615a25",
    "user": {
        "ext": {
            "AudienceData": []
        },
        "buyeruid": "7719d705c6abef5dc7ed6153dbcf963d"
    },
    "device": {
        "geo": {
            "country": "VNM",
            "city": "Hanoi",
            "lon": 105.85,
            "region": "VN-64",
            "type": 2,
            "lat": 21.0333
        },
        "ext": {},
        "carrier": "FPT Telecom Company",
        "ip": "1.55.255.255",
        "js": 0,
        "language": "en",
        "ua": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0",
        "devicetype": 2
    },
    "badv": []
}
```

As you can see it has nested key=>value I need to parse each key even the nested one's with their values?

Comment: `foreach ($items as $key => $value)`

Comment: Json_decode? If that's a string that is.

Comment: But I am unable to parse $value , if its again an array in key=>value?

Comment: Recursive function.

Comment: Can you please heip me with that function?    I wrote something but :(                                         function traverse(&$impression)
  {   }
    foreach ($bid as $key => &$value)
      if ($key=='imp')
      {traverse($value)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function validateRequest($arr, $path) {

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
    if (is_array($val))
        validateRequest($val, ($path!=""?$path . ">" . $key:$key));
```

elseif (!is_numeric($key)||is_numeric($key)) {

```
        echo "<br />".($path!=""?$path.">".$key:$key)."=".$val;
    }
```